# performance of xampp running on dropbox

Tags: performance, xampp, dropbox

i'm running xampp on my company notepad but would also like accessing it at home with my desktop pc which runs on a fast ssd. 
i considered moving my xampp directory to dropbox.
can someone tell me about performance issues - will the dropbox background sync processes affect my xampp's apache/mysql performance - when there's lots of permanent coding work / changes in my scripts - or will it perform just as fast as it would when located in `c:\xampp`? thanks

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't, when syncing you are basically downloading it to your PC, so you're running it from your local box. Since you are using ssd, I doubt you'll be using all your SSD power to the maximum and also you won't be using the internet when coding locally.

But it should be causing a bit of cpu/network usage although you're using xampp on a local box(the sync needs to check the files if they changed/added/removed + transfer changes). Consider pausing the sync while working on xampp, and start it back when done working on it.